# how can i divide items by categoria with twig

Tags: php, symfony, foreach, twig

im trying to divide my items by category with javascript and twig, so after bringing all the products from the database i dont know how can i separate products with {% for %}. this is my twig code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h5 class="panel-title truncate">Categoria:{{ producto.idCategoria }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Nombre:{{ producto.producto }}
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/savainventario/images/'~producto.filePersistencePath ) }}"
                 alt="404 file not found" class="img-thumbnail"/>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                {#Precio#}
                <span itemprop="price">
                 Precio:{{ producto.precio }}.Bsf
                </span>
                {#Form#}
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get"
                      action={{ path('sava_inventario_addcart', {'id': producto.idProducto }) }}>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Agregar">
                    </div>

                    {#Ver mas#}
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#myModal{{ producto.idProducto }}">
                    Ver mas...
                </button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{ producto.idProducto }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span
                                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{ producto.producto }}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Datos productos -->
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Nombre:</td>
                                        <td>{{ producto.producto }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Image:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/savainventario/images/'~producto.filePersistencePath ) }}"
                                                 alt="404 file not found"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Descripcion</td>
                                        <td>{{ producto.descripcionProducto }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Precio:</td>
                                        <td>{{ producto.precio }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cantidad:</td>
                                        <td>{{ producto.cantidad }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Categoria:</td>
                                        <td>{{ producto.idCategoria.categoria }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Modelo:</td>
                                        <td>{{ producto.idModelo.modelo }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Video:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <iframe width="433" height="315"
                                                    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/tQShyqnRx3s?list=PLw4rBoBPv1Vbq16M4SFkJPZj08FMaaR-8"
                                                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div> {#footer end#}
    </div>
</div>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

</div>
</div>
```

my question is how can i separate my items by category, in one category i print it in one div container, in another div container i add products from another category and so on.

Comment: Look up control break algorithm. Here is an example in C - http://pastebin.com/sArUmwRa

Comment: you can't break for loops in twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html.

Comment: Why would you want to break it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entites are setup properly this shouldnt be hard:

```
//Contoller

/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function showProductsByCategory()
{
    $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository("NamespacedBundle:Category")->findAll();
    return array(
        'categories' => $categories
    );
}
```

Assuming your categories know about products

```
//Category Entity
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
 protected $products;
```

And your products are tied to the category

```
//Product Entity
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="category_id")
 */
 protected $category;
```

Then your twig could be something based on:

```
//Sample Twig
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{category.name}}</h1>
        <ul>
        {% for product in category.products %}
            <li>{{product.name}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: since im using elasticsearch and not doctrine, i cant use this method, still gave me an idea in how to solve it. thanks for your answer.